# How to update state?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to update state with API.

I tried to update API state with using setouttime,

in render(), there is if statement which if timepassed is true, this.get_bus will be called to update state.
However I got warning cannot update during an existing state transition

Please let me know how to update.

**Code**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      station1: [],
      station2: [],
      timePassed: false,
    }
  }

  get_BUS(code, station) {
    return fetch('https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/' + code + '/live.json?app_id=6ab4b5a0&app_key=7693c12908e7d566351e3610b4acfa9f&group=route&nextbuses=yes')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        for (var x in responseJson.departures) {
          this.setState({
            state: this.state[station].push(responseJson.departures[x][0]["line"], ": ", responseJson.departures[x][0]["aimed_departure_time"], " ")
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.get_BUS('01000053207', 'station1')
    this.get_BUS('01000053207', 'station2')
    this.setTimePassed(false)
  }
  setTimePassed(abc) {
    this.setState({ timePassed: abc });
  }

  render() {
    ...

    let that = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
      that.setState({ timePassed: true })
    }, 10000);

    if (this.state.timePassed) {
      console.log("HI update")
      this.get_BUS('01000053207', 'station1')
      this.get_BUS('01000053207', 'station2')
      this.setTimePassed(false)
    }

    return (
      ......
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's why you would get that error: When you update state, you use

```
this.setState({ ... });
```

However, `this.setState({ ... })` method will call `render()` method when the state has been updated. Therefore, you're repeatedly calling `render()` as you update states in it before the `return` block.

If I get it right, you want to call `get_bus()` every 10 seconds. Look at the following example first, in this example, I have state:

```
this.state = {
    timer: null,
    counter: 0
};
```

Where `timer` is a timer, it will call the function we want to execute every time some seconds have passed, and we use `counter` to count how many seconds have passed, look at the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timer: null,
            counter: 0
        };

        this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
    };

    // Set up our timer here
    componentDidMount() {
        let timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
        this.setState({ timer });
    }

    // Add 1 to counter for every second passed
    tick() {
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ ... }}>
                <Text style={{ ... }}>
                    {this.state.counter}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, in `componentDidMount()`, we use `setInterval()` method to set up our timer. `setInterval()` methods takes 2 arguments, the first argument is the function you wish to execute, the second argument is the interval in milliseconds, this is what the app looks like:

[image]

In your case, if you wish to call `get_bus()` every 10 seconds, simple change the two arguments to `this.get_bus(...)` and `10000`

Comment: Thanks, it totally works for me. I am just wondering what   this.tick = this.tick.bind(this); means ?

Comment: In `componentDidMount` there’s this statement: `let timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000)`, where we call `tick` method without `()`, meaning that we don’t want to execute it yet, only when something else has happened, then we want to execute it, in this case, we want to execute it when every 1 second passes. Generally, when you call a function without `()`, you should `bind` that function, you can 1. Do it in the way I did, or 2. Delete that `bind` statement in my code and define `tick` function this way: `tick = () => { ... }`, which is called a fat arrow function. The first way is faster

Comment: If the function you wish to execute doesn’t take any argument, you should probably do it the first way, if it does take arguments, then do it like this: `let timer = setInterval(() => this.get_bus(arg1, arg2), 10000);` and I believe you still need to `bind` this function, or maybe not, I have not tried before